# MediaWiki: activate Visual Editor for all NameSpaces by default

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I would like to activate the extension [VisualEditor](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:VisualEditor) by default to all available and future [Namespaces](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Namespace) by default in [MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki). In particular see section [Changing active namespaces](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:VisualEditor#Changing_active_namespaces) of the VisualEditor extension page mentioned above.

This means that I would like to (if possible):

- avoid having to modify LocalSettings.php after having added a Namespace;
- avoid having to modify source code in MediaWiki itself;
- avoid having to modify source code in MediaWiki Extensions (namely VisualEditor).

I saw that there has already been attempts in doing this [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:Spky5rat787g67fj) but it didn't work when I tried the suggested modification and it violated my rule of wanting to avoid modifying any source code (see bullet points above).

I was thinking about something like this in LocalSettings.php (based on section *Changing active namespaces* mentioned above):

```
$wgVisualEditorAvailableNamespaces = [
    * => true
];
```

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to use the namespace id in your LocalSettings.php. As a consequence, you can configure your future namespaces in advance. When you will create your next namespace, it will be already configured. Please find below an example:

```
for ($x = 3000; $x <= 4000; $x++) {
    $egApprovedRevsEnabledNamespaces[$x] = true;
    $wgVisualEditorAvailableNamespaces[$x] = true;
}
```

I have tested and it worked.
See you soon Pit ;)

Comment: ... and of course you can give a real name to your namespace i.e "My Namespace". In the LocalSettings.php we are using the index of the namespaces array.

Comment: This is not working for me.